# How to find two related vertexs in Orientdb

Tags: orientdb

There is one Class API inherited from V, it have three properties: name, arguments and return_value,the following is an example:

{
"api": "_mbscmp",
"arguments": 
[
 "0x029605c8",
 "0x10011a74"
],
"return_value": "-1",
}

I have created 3000 API vertexs, next I want to create two edges:

1.Argument_sharing: two API vertexs have a same parameter,for example, API one has parameters ["1","2","3"] and API two has parameters ["X","y","1"], one and two will have a edge Argument_sharing, which means one and two have the same parameter "1"

2.Data_dependence: one API's return_value is same as one of the parameters of the other one. for example, a = APIone(); APItwo(a); then APIone and APItwo will have a Data_dependence edge.

So I want a sql command to find two related vertexs

Comment: Could be helpfull for you a javascript function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with these records

[image]

I used this javascript function

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var api_list=g.command("sql","select from API");
for(i=0;i<api_list.length;i++){
    var api=api_list[i];
    var arguments=api.getProperty("arguments");
    for (j=i+1;j<api_list.length;j++){
        var api2=api_list[j];
        var arguments2=api2.getProperty("arguments");
        for(h=0;h<arguments.length;h++){
            var arguments_h=arguments[h];
            for(y=0;y<arguments2.length;y++){
                var arguments_y=arguments2[y];
                if(arguments_h==arguments_y){
                    g.command("sql","create edge Argument_sharing from " + api.getId()+ " to " + api2.getId());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I got these records

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I also use the similar method you mentioned to implement the function. But what I want is letting Orientdb to handle this , which means just using sql commands. I think, handling this inside Orientdb may be more efficient. Anyhow, thanks for your answer!